# Select specific attribute directive using ViewChild in Angular

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

I have a couple elements that utilize the [mdTooltip](https://material.angular.io/components/component/tooltip) attribute directive (That's what it's called [right](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html)?)

```
@Component({
    selector: 'status-bar',
    template: '<md-icon #iconOne mdTooltip="Connected">check_circle</md-icon>
               <md-icon #iconTwo mdTooltip="Disconnected">warning<md-icon>'
})
```

I'm able to call the `toggle()` method on `iconOne` by using:

```
export class StatusBarComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild(MdTooltip) myIcon: MdTooltip;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.myIcon.toggle();
    }
}
```

The way I understand it, the element to which I apply the Attribute Directive, kind of becomes the type of the attribute directive. So I tried to select `iconTwo` like this:

```
@ViewChild('iconTwo') myIcon: MdTooltip;
```

This results in an error once the code is hit:

> _this.myIcon.toggle is not a function

I'm guessing the item wasn't properly selected. How do I target that second icon and toggle it?

Comment: if you are having one instance of the `icon` `@ViewChild(..) myIcon` will work since there are two instances. @ViewChild will be conflicted between both. So you need to explicitly define it

Comment: @Aravind - Doesn't 'iconTwo' explicitly define it? I'm very new to Angular and I cannot find any documentation for this, probably because I don't know the terminology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an extra parameter to make Angular return you a ref to the directive

```
     @ViewChild('id2', { read: MyDir }) id2 : MyDir;
```

I don't think you need to do it for components. If a directive uses `exportAs` in the metadata, you can assign ref variable to the `exportAs` attribute.

```
 <div my-dir #id2="myDir"></div>
```

Here is an example:

```
 @Directive({
    selector: '[my-dir]'
  })
  export class MyDir{
    @Input() id: number;

    toggle() {
      console.log('say hi', this.id);
    }   
  }

  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <div>
        <button (click)="toggle2()">toggle 2</button>
        <h2 my-dir [id]="'1'">Hello 1</h2>
        <h2 my-dir #id2 [id]="'2'">Hello 2</h2>
      </div>
    `,
  })
  export class App {
    @ViewChild('id2', {read:MyDir}) id2 : MyDir;

    constructor() {
    }

    toggle2() {
      this.id2.toggle();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Why is this not clearly stated in the documentation... Any links to official documentation that describes this? I just see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html, and the "read" option in the metatdata is merely mentioned, but no examples :/

Comment: I know it is not well documented. I read Angular source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also bind to it and use 1 icon.

```
<md-icon [mdTooltip]="connectStr">{{icon}}</md-icon>
```

[Here's a Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hvAAJyRuV2QahkiupxEh?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I realized this, but I have even more than 2 icons on the page (the question is simplified), and I want to use this opportunity to learn more about Angular, specifically how to target elements that I need.